# Storing NFC credit card near NFC phone

Tags: nfc, google-pay

I have a quick question about NFC on Android devices. Assume that I have a device set-up for Google Pay, i.e. I added a credit card. I also have said credit card in my wallet and it is capable of NFC transactions (i.e. I can pay with the creadit card in the same way as I can pay with my phone).

The battary drain of NFC on phones is negligible these days, mostly due to the low power consumption when in "passive" mode. But whenever you do a payment, the chip switches to "active" mode to actually process the payment.

If I put my phone with NFC enabled onto my wallet (containing the NFC-capable credit card), will the phone be constantly in active mode and thus consume more power?

Comment: AFAIK NFC is disabled when the screen is switched off/locked (and it needs root-powered "hacks" to work around that): So as long as your device is locked, there should be no danger of "accidental activation". You could verify that with your next real payment: try okaying it with the device locked / screen off and see what happens. If "nothing", switch screen on (still locked) and try again. According to the above, it should still not work – and only kick in when you unlock the device.